# Somehow got Eclipse to prevent me from typing anything

Tags: java, eclipse

First off, I am brand new to computing and taking an intro to programming course which utilizes Java.

I've been working along with the first chapter of my book and having no major issues but I was having trouble figuring out how to create a new compilation unit so as to create a new class without using Eclipse's autocorrect option when the class name differs from that of the compilation unit. Anyhow, something I did removed the console display from the bottom of the screen and I couldn't type any code, anywhere. I figured out how to get the console box to reappear at the bottom but I still can't type anything into the main space and the bottom simply reads "No consoles to display at this time."

Please help. This is already overwhelming and frustrating and now I literally can't do anything, let alone move on in trying to learn this. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try exiting Eclipse and restarting?  If you're worried about losing your work, try to select your code, copy it, and paste it into a text file somewhere else, before exiting Eclipse.  If you don't know how to do that, first please tell us what kind of computer you're using (Windows, Mac, ...).

Comment: When you run a Java program from within Eclipse, the output appears in the Console view. What do you want to type into the console?

Comment: to restore the console `Window -> Show View -> Console` or `ALT+SHIFT+Q, C` src: [Eclipse where did my console go?](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/eclipse-3-2-where-did-my-console-go/14375/msg/114169/view.html#msg114169)